# Alternative for graphql subscriptions and Socket io/Client subscribe channel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I have used socket io and apollo subscription before, now I am looking for an alternative solution. I need something similar to subscriptions-transport-ws that allows client browser to subscribe events or channels from the server.

Simple example.
Let's say on the server-side is some kind of pub/sub broker. Now user opens an article and the comment section is updated in real-time. So when a user opens an article, he starts listening for events from that channel. It should work like on Twitter to display every new like and comment.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using socket io and apollo subscription? What is the concern behind? e.g. you want more lightweight solution?

Comment: You may checkout [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) and [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: I can not use apollo because I have made REST API and the last time I used socket io I had a performance issue.

Comment: Well I will try to build notification system with ws, eventsource